# The base of the Logarithm in ITK

Tags: radix, logarithm, itk

I encountered the word Logarithm in the following places of ITK. But I am not sure about the base of it. Can anyone tell me the base of the usually talked Logarithm in ITK. Is is 2 or 2.71827 (i.e. the e) or 10?

The LogImageFilter:
https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LogImageFilter.html

and LogarithmicSigmaSteps at here:
https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual function `LogImageFilter` executes is this:

```
return static_cast< TOutput >( std::log( static_cast< double >( input ) ) );
```

And that means base is `e`. `MultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter` also uses std::log (implying base `e`). Take a look at source [code](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/30206c0ec0cfecb6df9dec22e9a54e98463189db/Modules/Nonunit/Review/include/itkMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter.hxx#L320-L335).

Comment: Thank you. The document could have made this clearer. Or possibly is it common sense to use e as base for logarithm in image processing?

Comment: e is the default base for logarithm and exponential function in science. Unless base is explicitly stated, you should assume e. Base 10 used to be popular with manual logarithmic tables due to convenient coupling with decimal base number.